# C# Password Security Login System with SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

I want to start by just mentioning I'm a semi-beginner at C# and cyber security so any feedback is appreciated :)

What I think I need reviewing is the SQLite queries and maybe the hashing functions

I'm making a password manager project (sorry in advance for wall of code):

The supporting functions: (I probably don't need to worry about these)

```
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation;

//Just a function to check if the username/password inputted was valid format (you can probably ignore this)
private bool ValidLogin()
{
    string Message = "Enter a ";
    if (LoginTBUsername.Text == "")
    {
        Message += "username";
    }
    if (LoginTBPassword.Text == "")
    {
        if (LoginTBUsername.Text == "")
        {
            Message += " and a ";
        }
        Message += "password";
    }
    if (Message != "Enter a ")
    {
        LoginLabelError.Text = Message;
        LoginLabelError.Left = (LoginPanel.Width - LoginLabelError.Width) / 2;
        LoginLabelError.Visible = true;
        return false;
    }
    if (LoginTBPassword.Text.Length < 8)
    {
        LoginLabelError.Text = "Password must be 8 or more characters";
        LoginLabelError.Left = (LoginPanel.Width - LoginLabelError.Width) / 2;
        LoginLabelError.Visible = true;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//Simple hash system
private string Hash(string Password, byte[] Salt, int Iteration = 12288)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
        password: Password,
        salt: Salt,
        prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA512,
        iterationCount: Iteration,
        numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));
}
```

```
//The login code
private void LoginButtonLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!ValidLogin())
    {
        return;
    }
    
    //Gets the path to the folders im using
    string AppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
    string MDBPath = AppData + "\\Password Manager\\Accounts.mdb";

    //Since database doesnt exist, no point continuing to login
    if (!File.Exists(MDBPath))
    {
        LoginLabelError.Text = "Account not found";
        LoginLabelError.Left = (LoginPanel.Width - LoginLabelError.Width) / 2;
        LoginLabelError.Visible = true;
        return;
    }

    string Username = LoginTBUsername.Text;
    string Password = LoginTBPassword.Text;

    //Heres where i need feedback
    string Command;
    using (SQLiteConnection SQLite = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={MDBPath};Version=3"))
    {
        SQLite.Open();
     
        //Checks if username exists (returns if not)
        Command = $"SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Accounts WHERE Username = '{Username}'";
        if ((Int64) new SQLiteCommand(Command, SQLite).ExecuteScalar() == 0)
        {
            LoginLabelError.Text = "Account doesn't exist";
            LoginLabelError.Left = (LoginPanel.Width - LoginLabelError.Width) / 2;
            LoginLabelError.Visible = true;
            return;
        }

        //Could probably turn these two into single statement but dont know how
        Command = $"SELECT Password FROM Accounts WHERE Username = '{Username}'";
        string PasswordHash = (string) new SQLiteCommand(Command, SQLite).ExecuteScalar();

        Command = $"SELECT Salt FROM Accounts WHERE Username = '{Username}'";
        byte[] Salt = Convert.FromBase64String((string) new SQLiteCommand(Command, SQLite).ExecuteScalar());

        if (PasswordHash == Hash(Password, Salt))
        {
            LoginPanel.Visible = false;
            LoginTBPassword.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            LoginLabelError.Text = "Incorrect Password";
            LoginLabelError.Left = (LoginPanel.Width - LoginLabelError.Width) / 2;
            LoginLabelError.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The register code:

```
//Register code
private void LoginButtonReg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!ValidLogin())
    {
        return;
    }

    string AppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
    string MDBPath = AppData + "\\Password Manager\\Accounts.mdb";

    //Creates nessacary folders
    if (!File.Exists(MDBPath))
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(AppData + "\\Password Manager"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(AppData + "\\Password Manager");
        }
    }

    string Username = LoginTBUsername.Text;
    string Password = LoginTBPassword.Text;
    byte[] SaltByte = new byte[128 / 8];
    using (RandomNumberGenerator RNG = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
    {
        RNG.GetBytes(SaltByte);
    }
    Password = Hash(Password, SaltByte);
    string Salt = Convert.ToBase64String(SaltByte);

    //Heres where i need feedback
    string Command;
    using (SQLiteConnection SQLite = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={MDBPath};Version=3"))
    {
        SQLite.Open();

        Command = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Accounts (Username varchar(32), Password varchar(32), Salt varchar(32))";
        new SQLiteCommand(Command, SQLite).ExecuteNonQuery();

        //Checks if account doesnt already exist
        Command = $"SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Accounts WHERE Username = '{Username}'";
        if ((Int64) new SQLiteCommand(Command, SQLite).ExecuteScalar() > 0)
        {
            LoginLabelError.Text = "Account already exists";
            LoginLabelError.Left = (LoginPanel.Width - LoginLabelError.Width) / 2;
            LoginLabelError.Visible = true;
            return;
        }

        //Hides the login panel and clears the password box
        LoginPanel.Visible = false;
        LoginTBPassword.Text = "";

        Command = $"INSERT INTO Accounts VALUES ('{Username}', '{Password}', '{Salt}')";
        new SQLiteCommand(Command, SQLite).ExecuteNonQuery();

        //Creates a folder with id where i store the user specific passwords
        Command = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Accounts";
        Int64 RowCount = (Int64) new SQLiteCommand(Command, SQLite).ExecuteScalar();
        Directory.CreateDirectory(AppData + $"\\Password Manager\\Account{RowCount}");
    }
}
```

Comment: A tip: look at NuGet package "Bouncy Castle". It provides a lot of modern encryption and hashing algorithms.

Comment: I have never been a fan of keeping the salt stored near the application or the database and neither decrypting a hashed string!. because if the app can decrypt what is encrypted, then there is no reason to encrypt it in the first place!

Answer (score 3):

As is very common for starter code of this nature, your view, model and controller are all mashed together. `LoginPanel.Visible = false` is a view obligation; file operations are a controller obligation and username/password representation are a model obligation. These all need to be teased apart - do some reading on MVC or MVVM, or more traditional ideas of "business layer" / "data layer".

Don't do this:

```
    Command = $"SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Accounts WHERE Username = '{Username}'";
```

Use `EXISTS` instead of `COUNT(1)`, and never EVER leave your commands open to injection attack by doing naive string interpolation of user data. Use prepared statements instead.

These two statements here:

```
    Command = $"SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Accounts WHERE Username = '{Username}'";
    Command = $"SELECT Salt FROM Accounts WHERE Username = '{Username}'";
```

can be combined into one statement that issues a `SELECT Salt` with a predicate for the username. If no rows are returned, the username was wrong.

Rather than constructs like this:

```
Directory.Exists(AppData + "\\Password Manager")
```

use [System.IO.Path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-5.0) for concatenation. Even if you did need a backslash, use an `@` string to avoid the need for an escape.

This:

```
Command = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Accounts (Username varchar(32), Password varchar(32), Salt varchar(32))";
```

is something that should be done on application startup, not in the middle of a `LoginButtonReg_Click` UI call.

Comment: You say to create the table if not exists on application start-up. I'm really pedantic so i put it there if the table is deleted while the application is running.

Comment: Why would that ever happen? This should be a purpose-assigned database that should never have tables deleted, never mind have concurrent users.

Comment: The more important thing here (though I don't know whether SQLite supports it) is that your application user should not have DDL permission at all.

Comment: what if the file gets deleted while the application is running. With my code, it creates the DB file on connection (version 3 SQLite) and creates the table. Eh its be being pedantic